# Какую библиотеку использовать для сравнения двух текстов?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два текстовых поля, в них будет текст. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, эти два текста проверялись и на экране показывались отличия. Какую библиотеку для этого использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот хороший пример, думаю как раз то, что нужно

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html